# Heroku PHP Kills existing sessions

Tags: php, heroku

I have a PHP app on Heroku.  Users can sign up and sign in; so the sessions *do* work.

Whenever I make an update ("git pus heroku master") it kills the sessions of the users.  Users have to then log back in to the site.

Is there a way to ensure this doesn't happen with every update?

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178675/when-redeploying-app-on-heroku-php-sessions-disappear) was of similar topic but didn't help.

Comment: Does  your application use the built-in PHP sessions i.e. with `session_start()`?

Comment: Yes,all files start with:

 session_start();
 ob_start(); 

and end with:

 ob_end_flush();

Comment: What is happening is that php is restarting and as such all outstanding sessions are invalidated.  You need to implement session handling as described in in [PHP Session Handling on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-sessions)

Comment: That got me on the right track, thanks!  Now I'm running into the problem of "The requested PHP extension ext-memcached * is missing from your system.  Install or enable PHP's memcached extension." -- I'm on a Windows machine using MAMP.  Haven't figured out how to enable it yet...

Comment: This might get you on the right track...[How To Install Memcache on MAMP](https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/3997527)

Comment: Worth a note that it's ok to use session_start() and a session variable for temporary use, such a a web form with captcha, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku platform does not support persistent PHP sessions.  You need to use Memcachier addon

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier

For PHP:

```
  // Create memcache client
  $mSession = new MemcacheSASL();
  $servers = explode(",", getenv("MEMCACHIER_SERVERS"));
  foreach ($servers as $s) {
      $parts = explode(":", $s);
      $mSession->addServer($parts[0], $parts[1]);
  }

  // Setup memcache authentication
  $mSession->setSaslAuthData( getenv("MEMCACHIER_USERNAME")
                            , getenv("MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD") );
```

```
$mSession->add($key, $val, $expires);
$stored = $mSession->get($key);
$mSession->replace($key, array('_data' => $data), $expires);
$mSession->delete($key);
```